# Selecting 2 rows from same table for different criterias

Tags: mysql, join

I've tried many examples for inner joins, outer joins and even tried conjuring my own with guesses (which more than often works) but no luck here.

TABLE 1:
follower_user_id, followed_user_id

(note it's followe**R**_ and followe**D**_)

TABLE 2:
user_id, username

So I need two rows from TABLE 2 where one user_id matches follower_user_id and another row where user_id matches followed_user_id

Query within query works but I know this isn't the way to go...

```
SELECT f.*, u.*
FROM tbl_follows f, tbl_users u
WHERE follower_user_id = u.user_id
```

That's the basic query

```
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
    //here i make another query to get the username of the followed_user_id
}
```

Surely this can be done in a single query?

Thanks in advance

**--- UPDATE 1: Sample Data ---**

**tbl_users**

```
user_id    |    username
--------------------------------------
1          |    abc123
2          |    xyz789
3          |    nosey123
```

**tbl_follows**

```
follower_user_id    |    followed_user_id
-------------------------------------------
3                   |    2                 //nosey123 is following xyz789
3                   |    1                 //nosey123 is following abc123
1                   |    2                 //abc123 is following xyz789
```

`While Results` : 
`echo "$row[username] is following $row['???????']<br />"`

I'm looking for:

```
nosey123 is following xyz789
nosey123 is following abc123
abc123 is following xyz789
```

Comment: Why doesn't the first query do what you want?

Comment: @McAdam331 because I also need the username from another row in the same table that matches `followed_user_id` - in the first query, the username is for `follower_user_id`

Comment: Do you have any sample data/expected results/ what you're getting? I'm just having a hard time picturing this one.

Comment: @McAdam331 sure, i'll update the question with this info

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT f.*, u.*
FROM tbl_follow f
JOIN tbl_users u ON u.user_id = f.follower_user_id OR u.user_id = f.followed_user_id;
```

This should return two rows for each userID, since there will be one match for follower user and one match for followed user.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried this already but it returns the same username twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.user_id), A.username, B.*
FROM tbl_follow A
     JOIN tbl_users B 
          ON B.user_id = A.follower_user_id 
             OR B.user_id = A.followed_user_id;
```

Comment: Hi. Error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*), DISTINCT(B.*) FROM` - something to do with DISTINCT(A.*)

Comment: Ok so there's no error but not the expected results so I'm going to test it properly later and get back to you. Thanks again